# hessian calculation with division by zero for first derivative

Tags: partial-derivative, hessian-matrix

I am wanting to calculate the hessian from an example dataset that keeps evolving. At one particular data set, one of the parameters (z) does not change, which causes a division by zero for the derivative.

i was wondering strategies for handling this. Is the appropriate response to say 'there is no hessian', even though 2 out of the 3 parameters can calculate their portion of the hessian matrix?

also I was wondering in this case if my ∂x is supposed to be x3-x1, or x2-x1, and  if I am calculating these squared derivatives wrong by doing ∂²x = ∂x3-∂²dx2, or if ∂²x should really just be (x2-x1)².

∂²x = (x2-x1)² seems wrong to me since acceleration was always calculated by taking two sequential derivatives, (and not squaring a single derivative which might be constant)

Example data is below

```
x1 = 1    y1 = 2   z1 = 3   f1 = 9
x2 = 1.5  y2 = 5   z2 = 3   f2 = 11
x3 = 3    y3 = 3   z3 = 3   f3 = 14


∂²f  = 1      = (14-11)-(11-9)

∂x   = 2      = x3-x1
∂y   = 1      = y3-y1
∂z   = 0      = z3-z1

∂²x  = 2      = (x3-x2)-(x2-x1)  = (3-1.5) - (1.5-1)
∂²y  = 1      = (y3-y2)-(y2-y1)  = (3-5)   - (5-2)
∂²z  = 0      = (z3-z2)-(z2-z1)  = (3-3)   - (3-3)

∂x∂y = 2       
∂x∂z = 0      
∂y∂z = 0 

H = [
      ∂²f/∂²x    ∂²f/∂x∂y   ∂²f/∂x∂z
      ∂²f/∂y∂x   ∂²f/∂y²    ∂²f/∂y∂z
      ∂²f/∂z∂x   ∂²f/∂z∂y   ∂²f/∂z²
    ] 

H = [
      1/2      1/2      1/0
      1/2      1/1      1/0
      1/0      1/0      1/0
    ]
```

Comment: If a parameter doesn't change then why is it a parameter and not a constant?

Comment: it's just observations, sometimes it does change. x could be height, y could be weight, z could be hair color

Comment: If it's a parameter and not constant then the partials don't exist so the hessian doesn't exist. When taking derivatives some information is lost, which is the constant part of the function. If the function doesn't change then derivatives lose all the information and you can infer nothing.

Comment: ok. if you want to post that as the answer i can accept that if one of the parameters doesnt change, then the whole hessian just doesnt exist.